# How to integrate the Run command to be a Unity lens?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses

I want to integrate the run command to be a unity lens so I don't need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to run a command. It would then be reachable from dash like any other lens such as file, music, ..

Comment: Hey, do you intend to get the run command by pressing <super> key?

Comment: No, i wanna integrate it with Dash to be just another unity lens

Comment: Yeah, I have been wanting to ask that same question.  Run-command can remember command lines including options, which the other or regular Dash lenses don't.  It would be great to navigate back to those with just the mouse, on occasion.

Answer (score 1):

Not used it myself, but you might get some joy with 'quickly'.

The link below shows how it's used for a wikipedia lens, but it might help you with what you are trying to do...

http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/04/how-to-create-a-wikipedia-unity-lens-for-ubuntu/[wikipedia lens](http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/04/how-to-create-a-wikipedia-unity-lens-for-ubuntu/)